# Displaying information from JSON file

Tags: php, json, get

This project I'm working on involves some work at a hotel, where I am connecting to the server and getting a JSON response. I use `JSON_Decode` as such, `$output = json_decode($data, true);`

And the JSON data that I am working with looks like this:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "0.1",
    "data": {
        "roomCount": 105,
        "rooms": [{
            "room_number": "104",
            "services": [{
                "adult": {
                    "enabled": false
                },
                "room_charges": {
                    "enabled": false
                }
            }],
            "status": "OCCUPIED"
        }, {
            "room_number": "105",
            "services": [{
                "adult": {
                    "enabled": true
                },
                "room_charges": {
                    "enabled": false
                }
            }],
            "status": "OCCUPIED"
        }
```

I have created a form for a user to enter a room number, and then I am using the `GET` method to take that room number to another page `display_room_report.php`. See the form I created below.

```
<div id="form1">
    <form action="display_room_report.php" method="GET" name="reporting" id="reporting"><br />
          <label for="single_room">Enter Room Number</label>
          <input type="text" name="id" id="single_room" size="20" required><br><br>
          <input style="margin-top: 20px" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
```

In the form, I am using the `id` as the room number entry, I am wanting to display the remaining information that corresponds to that room number from the JSON data, on the new page, `display_room_report.php`. I have tried coding this but I can't get it to work. I rarely use JSON, so I'm not sure if i'm doing it correctly? I am grabbing in the room number as follows:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])){ 
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}
```

What I'd like to do is for the room number that is passed through, output that room numbers parameters, such as `adult: enabled or disabled` and `room charges: enabled or disabled`. I connect to the server to get the JSON response is as follows:

```
try {
    $message = "api\tjson\tget\trooms\n";
    $handle  = fsockopen("192.xxx.xx.xx", 5678);
    fwrite($handle, $message);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'ERRORS: We are unable to connect to the server', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
};
if ($handle == TRUE) {
    $data = '';
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $data .= fread($handle, 8192);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    $output = json_decode($data, true);
```

I can grab the entire list of information from the JSON data as follows:

```
<?php foreach($output['data']['rooms'] as $info): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $info['room_number']; ?></td>
                        <?php $services = reset($info['services']); ?>
                        <td><?php echo ($services['room_charges']['enabled'] == 1) ? 'ENABLED' : 'DISABLED'; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo ($services['adult']['enabled'] == 1) ? 'ENABLED' : 'DISABLED'; ?></td>                
                        <td><?php echo $info['status']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    </body>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

However, I need to grab the specific `id` room_number then output that room number's corresponding data. If a user enters room 104, i'd like to only display the information for room 104, on the page `display_room_report.php`

Thank you very much for checking this out. I tried to make sense of what i'm doing, if you need further explanation, please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php foreach($output['data']['rooms'] as $info): ?>
      <?php if($info['room_number'] == $id): ?>
          <tr>
               <td><?php echo $info['room_number']; ?></td>
                   <?php $services = reset($info['services']); ?>
               <td><?php echo ($services['room_charges']['enabled'] == 1) ? 'ENABLED' : 'DISABLED'; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo ($services['adult']['enabled'] == 1) ? 'ENABLED' : 'DISABLED'; ?></td>                
               <td><?php echo $info['status']; ?></td>
          </tr>
      <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This should work with the code you have now.

However, I would look into the API docs and see if you can look up info by room number.  If you can, then you can ajax post to the API and retrieve data specifically for that room (which would most likely be a smaller payload), then you can display that data on the page dynamically without out a page refresh.

Comment: Thank you @Jacob! I should have seen this myself, but I was expecting it to be more complicated than this. This will work for now, I appreciate your advice about the API, too.